# C# - Checking a part of string in Hashtable Key

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I have two .csv files -

File1 -

```
EmployeeId  Username         BranchId   NewJoinee EmpType  AccessDetails
5543101    abc.username      40000        0        64     60060||60060
5543102    someone.username  40000        0        64     52474||52474
5543103    ABC.someone       40000        0        NULL     NULL
5543104    XZ.someone        40000        0        64      pppA082||
```

The Access Details column contains details as ``CardNumber|SecretPin|TokenNumber```

Same is the File2

```
EmployeeId  Username         BranchId   NewJoinee EmpType  AccessDetails
5000101    abc.username      40500        0        64     5555||60060
5000102    someone.username  40500        0        64     52474||1234
5000103    ABC.someone       40500        0        NULL     NULL
5000104    XZ.someone        40500        0        64      10A082||5644
```

I have to compare these two files, my conditions are -

- If the card number matches but token Id doesn't, do nothing
- If the card number does not match but token Id matches, do nothing
- If the access details are null, then print this employee details to another file
- If both card number and token Id do not match, then print this employee details to another file

I am currently doing this but using this approach I am only able to implement the 1st condition.I am using hashtables to store the content of files. I am making cardnumber as key and rest of the details as value.

This is how I am storing values of File1

```
 if (!_File1.ContainsKey(cardnumber))
 _File1.Add(cardnumber, username + "," + branchId + "," + employeeID + "," + cardnumber + "," + tokennumber + "," + empType + "," + newJoinee);
```

In the simiar fashion,I am storing the contents of file2 in a different hashtable. Then I am doing the following to read file2 data and compare

```
//readingFile2 data
row = SplitCSV(line);

employeeID = row[employeeIndex].Trim().ToString();
username = row[UsernameIndex].Trim().ToString();
branchID = row[branchIdIndex].Trim().ToString();
newJoinee = row[njIndex].Trim().ToString();
emptype = row[emptypeIdIndex].Trim().ToString();
accessdetails = row[ValueIndex].Trim().ToString();

if (!accessdetails.Equals("NULL"))
{
    string[] values = value.Split('|');
    cardnumberfile2 = values[0];
    tokenumberFile2 = values[2];
}
else
{
    cardnumberfile2 = employeeID;
    tokennumberfile2 = "";
}

if(_file1.ContainsKey(cardnumberfile2))
{
   //reading values from File1
  
   // As cardnumber in file2 is present in the file1, then do nothing
}
```

I was wondering of perhaps I should store key as

```
key = cardnumber+tokennumber
```

and then perhaps do something that could search if a token Id or a cardnumber is present in this key or not.
because in the above approach, I can test if the cardnumber is present or not because it is the key in both Files, but this approach will fail if we have different cardnumbers and same token number(row 1 in the example table)

Secondly, I dont know how to deal with the null value column as there are no unique linking values for these records.

P.S - I don't own the data. I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 maps. Data structures can look like this:

```
List<ClassMappedToFileItem> fileData; //data loaded from the file
Dictionary<string, int> cardNumbers; // value is an index pointing to an item in the fileData list
Dictionary<string, int> tokenIds; // value is an index pointing to an item in the fileData list
```